# App not running after upgrading to Android Studio 3.5

Tags: android, android-studio

I upgraded Android Studio to 3.5
The android app code compiles ok
However when I try to run it on the connected Xiaomi Redmi 4, it gives the following error,

```
09/08 20:11:18: Launching 'app' on Xiaomi Redmi 4.
Installation did not succeed.
The application could not be installed.
Installation failed due to: ''pm install-create -r -t -g -S 7910440' returns error 'UNSUPPORTED''
```

The error itself is cryptic. It is not clear what is not supported. Is it the OS version of the phone, SDK version etc.

What could be the issue and how to resolve this?

**Update:**

The app compiles, installs and runs fine on a Galaxy S8+ running android 8.0.0. It is not running on Xiaomi Redmi running android 6.0.1

gradle config:

minSdkVersion 21    // Android version 5.0 (Lollipop)

targetSdkVersion 28 // Android version 9.0 (Pie)

Answer (score 1):

Finally after some research I got it working. Disabled developer mode on the phone. Then enabled it again and enabled all options like USB install, USB debugging etc, disabled MIUI optimization and rebooted the phone. After reboot, the app installed and is working fine

Comment: FWIW, i also tend to get a few issues with my Xiaomi, hopefully this helps me out too